# Cannot resolve method onItemClickListener in fragment

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-fragments, onitemclicklistener

I'm trying to implement an onClickListener from my adapter class to callback a method in my fragment. I followed an example but still getting an error for adapter.setOnItemClickListener in the fragment class and I can't see where the problem is.

This is in my onCreateView method in my fragment class where i'm getting the error:

```
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    ((BusAdapter) adapter).setOnItemClickListener(new BusAdapter.OnItemClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(View view, int position){

        }
    });

    return view;
```

This is the part of my adapter class that deals with the onClickListener:

```
    public BusAdapter() {
    }

    public interface OnItemClickListener{
        void onItemClick(View view, int pos);
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView timeTextView, destinationTextView, routeTextView, minsTextView;

        ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            this.timeTextView = v.findViewById(R.id.due);
            this.destinationTextView = v.findViewById(R.id.terminus);
            this.routeTextView = v.findViewById(R.id.route);
            this.minsTextView = v.findViewById(R.id.due_mins_text);
            v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    int position = ViewHolder.super.getAdapterPosition();
                    onItemClickListener.onItemClick(v, position);
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you post what is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

You should implement `setOnItemClickListemer(BusAdapter.OnItemClickListener listener)` method in the adapter yourself as it has specific signature.